# Align words around an image

Tags: microsoft-word

I need an advice with settings for words around an image.

So far I have achieved this:

[image: link to image]

And I need to do this:

[image: link to image]

The words should be aligned to the left side of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your paragraph to use **Justified** alignment instead of left alignment. Word will try to make the edges of the text line up.

[image]

For example:

[image: Text wrapping]